# Printbibliography command not working, even though citations in-text are presented

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, input

First of all, if I fail to provide the sufficient information for helping me, I am sorry for it. I do not ask questions here often.

I know this is a widely discussed matter, but I have tried to search the answer to my problem and I simply cannot find it.

The problem: I cannot print my bibliography with the \printbibliography command at the end of my document.

The difference between my problem and what I see in every other question is that there is [any number] instead of the bold citation key. For example, if the citation key is Williams2016, and this is my first citation, what I see is [1] and not **Williams2016**, which tells me that the citations are read correctly.

I believe that it might have something to do with the \input command. I am writing different chapters in different .tex files and using \input to place everything in the same document. I have the same bibliography code for another document where I did not place chapters in separate files and it works fine.

Can anyone help me out?

My document is as follows (what I believe is the relevant part). I'm using the MastersDoctoralThesis template available here https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
english, 
singlespacing,
parskip,
headsepline,
chapterinoneline, 
]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)
\bibliography{C:/Users/berna/Documents/Bibtex/Thesis.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\begin{document}

\input{Chapters/Introduction}
\input{Chapters/Methods} 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: did you run the external program `biber` for the bibliography?

Comment: I take it the files `Introduction.tex` and `Methods.tex` contain one or more `\cite` instructions -- is this the case? Moreover, since you've specified the option `backend=bibtex`, have you run BibTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs?

Comment: What happens if you move the \printbibliography directly behind \begin{document}?

Comment: Do you happen to have an `\end{document}` in `Methods.tex`?

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings in the `.log` or`.blg` files (the `.blg` is a simple text file even though Windows might report it to be a 'performance monitor report', you can open it just like any plain text file). If you write stuff after `\printbibliography` is that shown? How exactly does `\printbibliography` not work? Do you get no output at all, an empty page, at least the heading, ...?

Comment: @Herbert I did not, and I don't understand what you mean by "running externally".

Comment: @Mico They do, and in the pdf they appear correctly numbered in-text. How do you run just BibTeX? I ran the exact same preamble in another document and it worked fine.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I do! I can't believe I did this mistake. I feel quite dumb. Thank you for your help, I deleted it and it is fine now.

Comment: @Bernardo - "How do you run just BibTeX?" Assuming the main tex file is called `main.tex`, you'd first type `pdflatex main` and then  `bibtex main` at a command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [TorbjørnT.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t) I was able to solve the issue. The problem was that I added a `\end{document}` in the end of my `Methods.tex` file.

Naturally, this was causing the document to end earlier than required, and the command `\printbibliography` wasn't being read.